# how to pass header from views in token authentication in DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, token, django-rest-auth

I've 2 apps in my django rest framework project, namely 'accounts' and 'trello'. I've used token authentication of DRF. I've authenticated(validated) and generated token for the users trying to login in the views of my 'accounts' app. And for one of the views of my 'trello' app, I've set  `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)` and `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]` .I also have done necessary settings for `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES`.

My question is: How do I send header with the token key generated from my views of 'account' app to the view where it needs the user to be authenticated i.e. for the view in 'trello' ?

I've tried it this way:

accounts/views.py:

`import requests`

`myurl = "http://localhost:8000/trello/create/board/"`

`class LoginView(APIView):`

```
permission_classes = [AllowAny]
serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = request.data
    serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    print(serializer.validated_data['user'])
    user = serializer.validated_data['user']
    print("user", user)
    token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    requests.post(myurl, data=serializer.validated_data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token {}'.format(token)})
    # django_login(request, user)
    return Response({'token': token.key},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

trello/views.py:

I actually do not know how to catch the data here.I tried to post from the account's views using django requests. I tried using get method here but it is not working as I want it to. I probably have tried this the wrong way, but can anyone correct this?

Comment: Why do you need to send the header to another view? authentication happens at a global scale for every request if you have correctly specified the default authentication classes

Comment: @Ken4scholars No, it's not(the view with IsAuthenticated permission_class) allowing the user for that view. And that's obvious as the user has to provide the token through the header, so I want to add that token in the header on the user's behalf. And once the user provides the token in the header, then the DRF on its level will see if the user is the authenticated one or not based on the token or so...I mean that's what I understood so far!

Comment: You don't need to add the token to the header yourself, the client app needs to. Check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably missing the token authentication flow. Here is what happens:

1. A client requests for a token using login and password
2. Your `login` view (or `obtain-token` view as I prefer to call it) verifies the user credentials presented by the client and issues a token. Note that you don't need to perform any Django login here, all you need do is issue token
3. In subsequest requests, clients adds the token to the Auth header and DRF's `TokenAuthentication` class authenticates (this is where the login occurs) the request and adds the user object to the request
4. Voila! all your requests are now being authenticated and you can add the necessary permissions to your views (trello view for example)

Comment: sir let's get it clear here, can you please explore the 3rd point of yours? Are you saying that users have to manually add the token in the header everytime? If it is so, that's not comfortable for this app as user will have to access that view many times and I also will be providing logout view where I'm going to delete the token so as to force the user to login again.I don't want users to manually add the token everytime.Also, will you tell me where exactly I've to use `TokenAuthentication`? I've done the things upto the 2nd point of yours.

Comment: @user10058776 Don't confuse the user and the client application. After the first request is made to obtain the token, all subsequent requests just have to add the token to the header, until it expires or the user logs out, then you have to obtain the token again. Believe me, this is a simple API authentication flow compared to more complex ones like OAuth2. You do not have to do anything with the `TokenAuthentication` class apart from adding it to the `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` setting or adding it per view. Again, obtain token request is made only once until token expires

Comment: @user10058776 Just to make it clear, the user has no idea about the token. The frontend app (web or mobile app) does. They simply just exchange the user's password for a token and make requests using the token instead using the login and password every time (which isn't very safe). And that is the point of Token authentication

Comment: and how the token can be added to the header by client?

Comment: Well well, that's very simple if you know how to make a request using the client. Just add it like any other HTTP header. Now if you don't know how to add a HTTP header in the framework you're using to build the client, then I suggest you learn more about it before you continue. It needs to be in the `Authorization` header in the format `Authorization: Token <token>`

Comment: @user10058776 You can check https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ for more details on Token Authentication and don't forget to upvote and mark as answer if it answers your question

Comment: Your answer was helpful. yeah, the guide is not that useful for me in case of token authentication.

Comment: @user10058776 actually, everything you need for token authentication is there, including a view that issues tokens to clients. So the only thing you need to do is figure out how to implement the flow in your client. But like I already explained, it's quite simple and straightforward. Get credentials from user - obtain token using the credentials - cache token and add it to all requests. If token expires or user is logged out, repeat the flow

Comment: trying to implement... If could, I'd be the happiest person in the world now

Comment: Great. Goodluck!

Comment: @Ken4scholars how its different from oauth2? Please explain as I am new to this.

Comment: @DeepakGautam It isn't related to this question so please ask a new question about the difference between the plain token auth and OAuth2 as the answer will be helpful to others. You can also check for existing questions.